# GetAsync request data is returned. But page is waiting response from server. FormsAuthentication the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

So I'm calling a WEBAPI to return some json data asyncronously. Was working well yesterday. Today I have added some basic FormsAuthentication, users must sign in to login.aspx, then they are redirected to default.aspx where the acync call lies when a user clicks a button.

The problem is i can see the request hitting off AND returning the data i need from Fiddler, but the response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); line is never hit and the system just waits there, it doesn't even timeout.

How can i debug what's going on. it's already in a try catch.

Here's the code to the async call.

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.steampowered.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&include_appinfo=1&include_played_free_games=1&format=json");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw if error

            // Read & Deserialize data
            dynamic json_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            var gamecount = json_data.response.game_count;
            saveOwnedGames(json_data);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            lbl_results.Text = e.Message;   
        }
    }
}
```

HttpResponseMessage is the line it sticks on. But as mention i can see the data in fiddler..

[image]

Can anyone think why FormsAuthentication would mess up an async call? why doesn't it timeout? This exact code was working yesterday. If it helps here is the FormsAuthentication Code and my web config.

Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="x-requested-with"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="account/login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

  <!-- Specifies how ASP.NET globally enables the built-in validator controls to use unobtrusive JavaScript for client-side validation logic. -->
  <!-- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnSteamAPI" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=SteamAPI;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Login Page

```
protected void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((UserEmail.Text == "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx") && (UserPass.Text == "xxxxxxx"))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage
           (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
    }
    else
    {
        Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

How RunAsync is fired.

```
protected void FindGames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl_results.Text = err.Message;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you call `RunAsync`?

Comment: @StephenCleary I've just added that part for you. It's from a button click.

Comment: Calling `Wait` when using `async/await` is generally a huge red flag. This is a commonly recurring question SO and I suspect you will have an answer or two very soon.

Comment: @DanielKelley You've put me on the right track. By searching on this, I've got it working by getting rid of the .Wait() and prefixing the method with await (and adding async to the click also).


I will be wrighting an answer now, i wish i could give you the answer points. (If you post that answer i will accept it, as I can't answer my own question for 2 days) Thanks again.

Comment: @JGreasley It's fine. It would feel wrong for me to add an answer as I only understand why it's a problem because I've been using SO to learn about async/await and there are duplicate questions on the sire. Glad I could help though, and it''s goof you have things working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Props going to @DanielKelley for putting me in the right direction.

I removed the .Wait() prefixed the method with await, and added an async to the click.
I also added Page Async="true" to the top of the page.

Updated:

```
protected async void FindGames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await RunAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl_results.Text = err.Message;
    }

}
```

Now I'll be searching on why .Wait() does this for the rest of the afternoon i suppose.

Comment: Here's a writeup I did on [why `Wait` causes deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary will be going through this also. I'm certainly just learning Async...for better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `Wait` causes a deadlock. I explain this in full [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

By default, `await` will capture a "context" and resume the `async` method within that context. In ASP.NET, this is a request context called `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, which only allows one thread in at a time. So, when the HTTP result comes back, the `await` completes and schedules the continuation of the `async` method to the context. However, the context cannot be used because there is already a thread blocked in it (the one calling `Wait`).

The proper solution is to use `await` "all the way up". I discuss this principle further in [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).